# EntityFramework support for Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I am able to add EntityFramework to ASP.NET Core application that runs on top of  .NET Framework (not on .Net Core). The CR operations are working fine, but not able to enable migration since I am using Code First approach. But as per the link
[Limited support for EF6 in ASP Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6)

there are some limitations. Is there any work around for this to make happen?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third party tool that enables EF 6 Migrations with .NET Core https://github.com/mrahhal/Migrator.EF6

More information about EF6 with ASP.NET Core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6

Comment: Thank you. I checked the second link and tried the solution but it is not working. I am not able to add dependency for EF6

Comment: Did you create a standard Csproj class library project and add EF 6 to that (as described in the docs) ?

Comment: I am sorry I missed that part. Moreover I am having a ServiceFabric microservice application. So I added the EF 6 to the service project. Let me try what you mentioned.

Comment: The question states "not .Net Core".